# Does QT supports run time dynamic UI generation and HTML rendering

Tags: c++, qt, qtembedded

I am trying to consider QT for embedded device UI development.

But I want to have UI library that supports UI generation at the run time, for example, UI lib should support creating UI screen depending on the configuration stored in the file, code will read this file and will create UI XML or user the lib APIs to create the UI at run time, is this supported in QT?

Also does QT supports rendering basic HTML pages on the embedded UI, does it supports WebView like widgets to render HTML pages?

Answer (score 1):

> UI lib should support creating UI screen depending on the
>   configuration stored in the file, code will read this file and will
>   create UI XML or user the lib APIs to create the UI at run time, is
>   this supported in QT?

Yes, look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/quiloader.html

> Also does QT supports rendering basic HTML pages on the embedded UI,
>   does it supports WebView like widgets to render HTML pages?

They basic textview/textedit component support simple html, also
there is part of qt named qt webkit, it is work around webkit/blink,
to support complex html.

Comment: Thanks for replay, is QUiLoader is available in QT for embedded also and QWebView is the widget for displaying web pages, but same question is it available in QT for embedded? I am not able to find page where Qt lists all the features/widgets supported in QT for embedded.

Comment: @A_user The answer `it depends`. Since Qt4 there is no such thing like separated Qt for embedded. You just build qt for your device from the same sources as Qt for Windows/Linux/Mac OS X. So if you disable during configure build stage some components then you have no them, if not disable then you have them. Technacaly if there is support from Qt for you device, then no technical restrictions to you about ui loader, or qt webkit.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to have UI library that supports UI generation at the run
>   time, for example, UI lib should support creating UI screen depending
>   on the configuration stored in the file, code will read this file and
>   will create UI XML or user the lib APIs to create the UI at run time,
>   is this supported in QT?

[QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) is a markup language, offering cleaner and easier syntax than XML and integrates JavaScript. It works together with the QtQuick 2 API to create rich UI experience. It doesn't require compilation, can be easily generated, offers great graphics performance and can be created from a simple string. It is a more fullproof solution than using the QtWidget based `.ui` XML format since you can not only have UI markup, but behavior and logic in it as well. Also, it is network transparent - you can have the QML file or associated data remotely on a network or the internet and use it directly.

It also comes with a ready to use [WebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebkit-webview.html#details) component.